# Crashing down when trying to delete objects

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

My program crashes down when trying to delete my created objects. Thought it would be safe to delete objects that were created by using the keyword `new`.

Why does this happen?

Here is the code:

**Header**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<string>

template<typename T>
class Postgre {
public:
    Postgre();

    std::vector<T*> get_user();
    std::vector<T*> get_fake_user();

    ~Postgre();
};

class User {
public:
    User(short id, std::string first_name, std::string last_name) {
        this->ID = id;
        this->first_name = first_name;
        this->last_name = last_name;
    }

    short ID;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

class Fake_User {
public:
    Fake_User(short id, std::string user_name, std::string user_pw) {
        this->ID = id;
        this->user_name = user_name;
        this->user_pw = user_pw;
    }

    short ID;
    std::string user_name;
    std::string user_pw;
};
```

**source**

```
template<typename T>
Postgre<T>::Postgre() {

}

template<typename T>
Postgre<T>::~Postgre() {
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T*> Postgre<T>::get_user() {
    T* user = new T(1, "Peter", "Peters");
    std::vector<T*> result;

    result.push_back(user);
    delete user;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T*> Postgre<T>::get_fake_user() {
    T* fake_user = new T(2, "Beverly", "Peters");
    std::vector<T*> result;

    result.push_back(fake_user);
    delete fake_user;
    return result;
}

template class Postgre<User>;
template class Postgre<Fake_User>;
```

**main**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
   Postgre<User>* postgre = new Postgre<User>();

   //test User Class:
   std::vector<std::vector<User*>> list_user;
   list_user.push_back(postgre->get_user());

    std::cout << list_user[0][0]->ID << std::endl;
    std::cout << list_user[0][0]->first_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << list_user[0][0]->last_name << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    //test Fake_User Class:
    Postgre<Fake_User>* postgre2 = new Postgre<Fake_User>();

    std::vector<std::vector<Fake_User*>> list_fake_user;
    list_fake_user.push_back(postgre2->get_fake_user());

    std::cout << list_fake_user[0][0]->ID << std::endl;
    std::cout << list_fake_user[0][0]->user_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << list_fake_user[0][0]->user_pw << std::endl;

    //wait for keypress
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have dangling pointers stored in your vector.

Comment: `Thought it would be save to delete objects that were created by using the keyword 'new'` Yes - but it's unsafe to use pointers to those objects **after** they have been thus deleted.

Comment: It is unclear why you use dynamic allocation in the first place. What's wrong with `Postgre<User> postgre;` or `T fake_user(2, "Beverly", "Peters");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T*> Postgre<T>::get_user() {
    T* user = new T(1, "Peter", "Peters"); 
    std::vector<T*> result;

    result.push_back(user); // you copy the pointer into result
    delete user; // you delete the pointer, now user is dangling
    return result; // on exit, the pointer user in vector result is dangling
}
```

you return a vector that stores pointers that are were deleted (dangling). Note that `push_back` copies the pointer (i.e. the memory location), so it stores a memory location that's already marked as deleted.